# Python 3 - Using concurrent.futures to call multiple instances of a .exe in parallel

Tags: python-3.x, concurrent.futures

Ok, after a lot of fiddling about I now have a script using concurrent.futures in Python 3 that runs without falling over. The point of this script is:

1) Chunk a dictionary into small sub dicts.

2) For each pass of the function `test_printer` call an executable.

3) Do this is parallel rather than serial.

```
from itertools import islice
import subprocess
from collections import OrderedDict
import concurrent.futures

global pair_dict

pair_dict = {
    1: 'one',
    2: 'two',
    3: 'three',
    4: 'four',
    5: 'five',
    6: 'six',
    7: 'seven',
    8: 'eight'
}


global test_printer

fin_dict = OrderedDict(sorted(pair_dict.items()))


def test_printer(start_chunk, end_chunk):

    #sub_dict = dict(pair_dict.items()[start_chunk:end_chunk])
    sub_dict = dict(list(pair_dict.items())[start_chunk:end_chunk])

    for key, value in sub_dict.items():

        #print(key, value)

        subprocess.call(["C:\\mypath\\myfile.exe"])

        print(key, value)

    print('-' * 50)


with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:

    for i in range(2, 9, 2):

        start_chunk = i - 2
        end_chunk = i

        test_printer(start_chunk, end_chunk)
```

...previously the code within scope of `concurrent.futures` was just a basic function that operated in serial. However, the same behaviour is observed using `concurrent.futures` as a basic function...i.e. one pass of the loop = one instance of the .exe called.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The fix for this was changing:

```
subprocess.call(["G:\\WebGrab+Plus\\bin\\WebGrab+Plus.exe"])
```

...to:

```
subprocess.Popen(["G:\\WebGrab+Plus\\bin\\WebGrab+Plus.exe"])
```

...this opens a series of the same executable in parallel. I'm getting a broken pool error now in relation to `concurrent.futures`, but I've resolved my stated problem...